# Batch - Extract string before the specified character

Tags: batch, batch-file, string-manipulation

How to get the string before the character hyphen? The following code gets the string after the hyphen. How can I reverse this?

```
set string=1.0.10-SNAPSHOT

echo %string:*-=%

SNAPSHOT
```

But I want the 1.0.10 instead of SNAPSHOT

Comment: Hello, Powershell guy here. If you're interested, in Powershell it would be the equivalent to this: `$string ='1.0.10-SNAPSHOT'; $string.split('-')[0]`. We can use the .Net `.split()` method to *split* the string at the hyphen, and grab just the first part of the newly created array using the *array index operator* (`[0]`). 0 is used as arrays start with 0.

Answer (score 4):

Use for with delims like this:

```
set string=1.0.10-SNAPSHOT
for /f "delims=-" %%i in ("%string%") do echo %%i
```

Answer (score 2):

> *The following code gets the string after the hyphen. How can I reverse this?*
>
> ```bath
> echo %string:*-=%
> ```

- See: ***[Split string into substrings based on delimiter](https://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=6429)***

> ...*And there’s a kludgy way to get the start of a string up to the first occurrence of the substring:  **[- Sponge Belly](https://www.dostips.com/forum/memberlist.php?mode=viewprofile&u=4238)***
>
> ```bath
> set "head=%str:x=" & rem."%"
> ```

- Porting to your variable and delimiter:

```bath
set "string=%string:Your_Delimiter=" & rem."%"
set "string=%string:-=" & rem."%"
```

- A shorter version would be:

```bath
echo\%string:-=&rem\%
```

- This also works by replacing `rem\` with `::`

```bath
echo\%string:-=&::%
```

- Outputs:

```bath
1.0.10
```

**Obs.:** Use without "double quotes" when echoing the variable so as not to escape the self-expanding variable

```bath
> set string=1.0.10-SNAPSHOT
> echo %string:-=&::% "%string:-=&::%"
       1.0.10         "1.0.10&::SNAPSHOT"
```

---

---

If the non-numeric string is always this one or it's always the same length, you can also remove the last 9 characters:

```bath
set string=1.0.10-SNAPSHOT

echo %string:~0,-9%

1.0.10
```

---

A non-loop alternative would be to use the current output of your substring as replace:

```bath
 cmd /v /c echo\ !string:-%string:*-=%=!
```

- Outputs:

```bath
1.0.10
```

---

#### Additional Resources:

- [`Set /?`](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)
- [DelayedExpansion (Refer: `cmd /v /c`)](https://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html)
- [`Set variable=variable:substrings` | DOS - String Manipulation](https://www.dostips.com/DtTipsStringManipulation.php)